# Filesystem.php - failed to open stream

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I made multiple web-applications using Laravel so this is not my first production deply. However - I've bumped into a weird issue that I can't seem to find the answer for. As with all applications I've done so far - I copy/pasted all the files to the production server, set up the .env file, edited app.php and database.php in the config folder but i keep getting this error:

```
    ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412:
     include(/home/xxxxx/public_html/appname/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php): 
    failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    in ClassLoader.php line 412
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'include(/home/xxxxx/public_html/appname/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory', '/home/xxxxx/public_html/appname/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php', '412', array('file' => '/home/xxxxx/public_html/appname/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php')) in ClassLoader.php line 412
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile() in ClassLoader.php line 412
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/xxxxx/public_html/appname/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php') in ClassLoader.php line 301
at ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem')
at spl_autoload_call('Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem') in Application.php line 539
at Application->registerConfiguredProviders() in RegisterProviders.php line 17
at RegisterProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 253
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 144
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Now... I've tried everything i found on the web so far. Clearing cache, checking file permissions, running composer dump autoload, reuploading all the files - but nothing seems to help. It's a shared hosting with PHP v5.6 which already has several laravel applications running and they work perfectly. The only difference is that this one is laravel 5.3 and the other are 5.2.

I have no errors on my local dev machine.

Any ideas!?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the /vendor directory and running `composer install` on the shared host?

Comment: I know you said you tried it but it sounds like permission issues. Have you tried using git and perhaps forge for your deployments?

Comment: Turnes out it was some security feature that was active on the hosting itself. For some reason, the mentioned class got flagged as malware and it kept getting deleted in various timespans. So sometimes the app wouldn't work at all, and sometimes it would just stop working after a couple of seconds/minutes.

Since my FTP client never refreshed itself - it always showed the file right where it was supposed to be. I contacted the hosting company and they fixed the issue.

Comment: @Skipp It would be nice if you made an answer out of this comment and accepted it so that other people find it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen due to some security features that are active on the web hosting itself. The mentioned class gets flagged as malware and the AV keeps deleting it upon upload/reupload. Since the whole file/class is missing - the application throws the mentioned error.

If you don't run your own server and can't white-list the file, just contact your hosting provider to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/filesystemphp .
It may be because of the exec function that is used in function link. Just remove this part:

```
/**
 * Create a hard link to the target file or directory.
 *
 * @param  string  $target
 * @param  string  $link
 * @return void
 */
public function link($target, $link)
{
    if (! windows_os()) {
        return symlink($target, $link)
    }

    $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';

    exec("mklink /{$mode} \"{$link}\" \"{$target}\"");
}
```